# How do I reserve a name for my iOS app so that no one else can use it?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

At what point in the iOS development process using Xcode is my app name reserved on App Store? (There are no updated answers to this question in any posts at stackoverflow.) Last I remember when I published my iOS app for sale status on iOS App Store at App Store Connect I had to change my published app name because there were already other apps using that name. I think that was the name that was actually showing on the App Store, and not the name I put in the Product Name field when I first create the project in Xcode.
I just tried to validate my iOS app and it wouldn't validate because it said there was already an app with that "App Name". I take it that means the name I put in the Product Name field when I first created the project, if I don't change it later. Is that correct?
So if my iOS app project validates, does that mean I have that App Name reserved so that no one else can use it?
How do I reserve a name for my iOS app so that no one else will get it once I reserve it?

Comment: I just create a new app in appstoreconnect & upload app later when finished...

Answer (score 3):

As someone said in the comments, simply create a new app in App Store Connect with the name you have in mind, then no-one else can use it. You don't have to send it to Apple immediately after you do this, you can wait however long you need to until it's ready.

Just make sure the bundle identifier is the same between the two.